# csvreader merge two files columnwise in table

Tags: tables, csvsimple

I would like to put together data columnwise!
Ideally I would like to take it from the same file, please see the example below.

```
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{filecontents*}{A.csv}
year,colA
2016,1
2016,3
2017,0
2017,2
\end{filecontents*}
```

I know how to get one column, now I would like to put the 2017 column "next to it" if that makes sense..

```
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!ht]\centering
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}%
    \hline year & colA
    \csvreader[head to column names,filter ifthen=\equal{\year}{2016}]{A.csv}{}
    {\\\hline \year & \colA }
    \\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

My intended outcome would look something like this:

```
\begin{table}[!ht]\centering
\begin{tabular}{|l|l||l|l|}%
    \hline year & colA & year & colA\\\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{2016}&1 &\multirow{2}{*}{2017}&0\\
                     &3 & &2
    \\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```